# Find vertex position on an edge loop (python)

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertices, edges

I have a list of vertices that make up an edge loop (the edge of a rectangle with multiple subdivisions, in this case.) I also know which vertices are at the start and end of the loop.

What method can be used to find the position of a given vertex in the edge loop? I want to make an ordered list of which is 2nd from the start, 3rd from the start, etc. Is there any tools/utilities to help with this? Or an optimal way?

I assume it could be found by "walking" down the loop in some way, such as finding which edges are connected to the start vertex, and then find the next in the loop by seeing which other vertices in the list share the same edge. This seems inefficient though. Is there a better option?